# Formatting Error Message in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a stock validation error message that displays on the top of the screen when a field isn't met. I would like to format the message so that they display next to the field, instead of on the top of the screen. Does anyone know how I could do that?

Comment: You need to post code and exact errors/problems that you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gem out there called [client_side_validation](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) which does exactly what you are looking to do. Also check out the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations?view=asciicast) for an example on how to get set up with the validation library.